# How to call function inside itself

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that I want to call again inside, after the last line finishes.

Maybe it will be more understandable if I show code.

```
function updateQuantity(){ 
    // further code where I change same data
    // and now I want to start function again but with remembering the input element that called it previously 
    updateQuantity(this);  // I tried it this way but it doesn't work
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: What about that doesn't work? That's a classic case of recursion (except you need a terminating condition). Are you trying to have the same `this` value when you call it again?

Comment: @MikeC Maybe OP is trying to preserve the variables set in the previous run of `updateQuantity`?

Comment: I want to function remember input element that I want to use in this function

Answer (score 8):

The answer is simple, it is enough to use `updateQuantity.call(this)` inside the `updateQuantity` function - when we use `call` and add `this`, the function will start again and remember the input element that previously called `updateQuantity`.

Answer (score 4):

From the comments to your question, it seems like you want to pass a value to your recursive method call.

```
function updateQuantity(val){
  // Do something with `val`
  val = val + 1;

  console.log(val);

  // And call it again with the value
  if(val < 5){
    updateQuantity(val);
  }
}

updateQuantity(1); // 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Comment: Not value but I want ther input element that previously call this function because inside it I want to use this input element.

Comment: You mean original argument value? Then, just don't change it and pass it as it is. Remove `val = val + 1;` from the code above.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to get that DOM element in the function body.

This is a simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/c3kbu0j7/10/

HTML

```
<a href="#">element you want.</a>
```

JavaScript

```
$('a').on('click',function(){
    a(this);
});
var i=0;
function a(tar){
  console.log(tar);
  if(i<4){
    i++;
    a(tar);
  }
  i=0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `requestAnimationFrame()`, which calls the function every frame.

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="link"></a>
```

JS

```
const link = document.getElementById("link");

function myFunc(value) {
      ///////////////////
     // do stuff here //
    ///////////////////
    
    // call the function again with the same parameter
    requestAnimationFrame(myFunc(value));
}

link.addEventListener("mousedown", function () {
    myFunc(link);
}, false);
```

Or, if you want the function to just be called twice:

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="link"></a>
```

JS

```
const link = document.getElementById("link");
let x = 0;

function myFunc(value) {
      ///////////////////
     // do stuff here //
    ///////////////////
    
    // call the function again but increase x so an infinite loop isn't created
    if (x < 1) {
        x++;
        myFunc(value);
    }
    else x = 0;
}

link.addEventListener("mousedown", function () {
    myFunc(link);
}, false);
```